# Set both end_ and start_time in form with datetime_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

Im trying to set up a bookings form where people can book services. Within the Service model there is a duration set and I want to use this to automatically populate the end_time. For example, if I book a 60 minute service at 2017-03-22 1PM I want the end time to be set at the same day but one hour later. Is it possible to send this in with a form?

```
<%= form_for([service, service.bookings.new]) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <%= hidden_field_tag "recipients", @user.id %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag 'Available times' %>
        <%= f.datetime_select :start %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :end, value: Time.at([:start].to_i + service.duration) %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :service_id, value: service.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :price, value: service.price %>
      </div>
      <%= submit_tag 'Book', class: 'btn btn-complete btn-lg btn-large btn-block' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've tried with above but get

> undefined method `to_i' for [:start]:Array

which I guess is because :start is not yet saved and renders nil.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[:start] is just return an Array contain symbol, and you can not get anything.

You should create end_time in controller or model when you got the start_time, or other way is using the javascript code get end_time when type start_time in the form

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas on how I can create that end_time in the controller properly? The following code doesn't work for the reasons stated in above comment.
`booking_params[:end] = Time.at(booking_params[:start].to_i + Service.find(booking_params[:service_id]).duration)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider not doing business logic in a view. Send these params and set the end variable in model or controller.

Why does your code not work?
`datetime_select` [returns a set of select tags (one for year, month, day, hour, and minute).](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this totally makes sense. Since I get back a bunch of select tags, do you have an idea on how to solve this problem in the controller? The following code obviously doesn't work 
`booking_params[:end] = Time.at(booking_params[:start].to_i + Service.find(booking_params[:service_id]).duration)`

Then after that calling the create

`@booking = current_user.bookings.create(booking_params)`